# Autotesting of business processes in Camuda 8

Tags: automated-tests, camunda

I am new to Camunda. I work as a QA for a company that is implementing version 8 of the system.
I have a problem with autotests. I found examples of writing autotests for version 7, but absolutely nothing for version 8. Maybe you have some information for a poorly understood autotester?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use camunda 8 yet, but have you tried using the bpmn driven testing modeler plugin https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/bpmn-driven-testing?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "automated unit tests" by "autotest," this is possible in Java with Camunda 8 as well:

- Spring Boot: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/spring-zeebe#writing-test-cases
- Plain Java: https://github.com/camunda/zeebe-process-test

See for example this test case using Java, Spring Boot and Camunda 8: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-8-examples/blob/main/twitter-review-java-springboot/src/test/java/org/camunda/community/examples/twitter/TestTwitterProcess.java